# Open edit mode for a row programmatically if a cell is not visible. Ag Grid, Vue.js

Tags: vue.js, focus, ag-grid, visible, invisible

How could I open edit mode for a row programmatically if a cell is not visible?

In my case the cell is not visible due to a large number of columns. [Here](https://plnkr.co/edit/EqL5KWq1WYX1wOsd?open=main.js) is a reproducible example:

```
import 'ag-grid-community/dist/styles/ag-grid.css';
import 'ag-grid-community/dist/styles/ag-theme-alpine.css';
import 'ag-grid-enterprise';
import { AgGridVue } from 'ag-grid-vue';
import Vue from 'vue';

const VueExample = {
  template: `
        <div style="height: 100%">
            <div class="example-wrapper">
                <div style="margin-bottom: 5px;">
                    <button style="font-size: 12px" v-on:click="onBtStartEditing()">Start Editing Line 2</button>
                    <button style="font-size: 12px" v-on:click="onBtStopEditing()">Stop Editing</button>
                </div>
                <ag-grid-vue
                
                style="width: 100%; height: 100%;"
                class="ag-theme-alpine"
                :columnDefs="columnDefs"
                @grid-ready="onGridReady"
                :defaultColDef="defaultColDef"
                :editType="editType"
                :rowData="rowData"
                @cell-value-changed="onCellValueChanged"
                @row-value-changed="onRowValueChanged"></ag-grid-vue>
            </div>
        </div>
    `,
  components: {
    'ag-grid-vue': AgGridVue,
  },
  data: function () {
    return {
      columnDefs: [
        {
          field: 'make',
          cellEditor: 'agSelectCellEditor',
          cellEditorParams: {
            values: ['Porsche', 'Toyota', 'Ford', 'AAA', 'BBB', 'CCC'],
          },
        },
        { field: 'model' },
        { field: 'field4', headerName: 'Read Only', editable: true },
        { field: 'price', cellEditor: NumericCellEditor },
        {
          headerName: 'Suppress Navigable',
          field: 'field5',
          suppressNavigable: true,
          minWidth: 200,
        },
        { headerName: 'Read Only', field: 'field6', editable: true },
      ],
      gridApi: null,
      columnApi: null,
      defaultColDef: {
        flex: 1,
        editable: true,
      },
      editType: null,
      rowData: null,
    };
  },
  created() {
    this.editType = 'fullRow';
    this.rowData = getRowData();
    for(let i = 0; i < 1000; ++i) {
      this.columnDefs.push({ headerName: 'Read Only', field: 'field6', editable: true });
    }
  },
  methods: {
    onCellValueChanged(event) {
      console.log(
        'onCellValueChanged: ' + event.colDef.field + ' = ' + event.newValue
      );
    },
    onRowValueChanged(event) {
      var data = event.data;
      console.log(
        'onRowValueChanged: (' +
          data.make +
          ', ' +
          data.model +
          ', ' +
          data.price +
          ', ' +
          data.field5 +
          ')'
      );
    },
    onBtStopEditing() {
      this.gridApi.stopEditing();
    },
    onBtStartEditing() {
      this.gridApi.setFocusedCell(1, 'make');
      this.gridApi.startEditingCell({
        rowIndex: 1,
        colKey: 'make',
      });
    },
    onGridReady(params) {
      this.gridApi = params.api;
      this.gridColumnApi = params.columnApi;
    },
  },
};

window.getRowData = function getRowData() {
  var rowData = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    rowData.push({
      make: 'Toyota',
      model: 'Celica',
      price: 35000 + i * 1000,
      field4: 'Sample XX',
      field5: 'Sample 22',
      field6: 'Sample 23',
    });
    rowData.push({
      make: 'Ford',
      model: 'Mondeo',
      price: 32000 + i * 1000,
      field4: 'Sample YY',
      field5: 'Sample 24',
      field6: 'Sample 25',
    });
    rowData.push({
      make: 'Porsche',
      model: 'Boxster',
      price: 72000 + i * 1000,
      field4: 'Sample ZZ',
      field5: 'Sample 26',
      field6: 'Sample 27',
    });
  }
  return rowData;
};

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  components: {
    'my-component': VueExample,
  },
});
```

Once the application opens just scroll to the most right of the table. Then click the `Start Editing Line 2` button. The result is that no row gets transferred into the edit mode. That is because the `make` column gets removed from DOM.

Now, refresh the page and click the `Start Editing Line 2` button without scrolling anywhere. The result is that the second row goes into the edit mode.

So, how can I transfer a row into an edit mode if not all cells are visible? I.e. in the former case I would like the `Start Editing Line 2` button to keep working.

If the cell is not visible I would prefer not to focus any cell and still get the row transferred in the edit mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another option I found is to set the `suppressColumnVirtualisation` to `true`. This way the whole row is drawn to HTML all the time (even on scroll to the most right). This way we can be sure that the focused cell will exist all the time and so the edit mode will get opened just fine.

More details [here](https://www.ag-grid.com/vue-data-grid/dom-virtualisation/).

Answer (score 2):

You can pin the "make" column (temporarily or permanently)

```js
onBtStartEditing() {
  this.gridColumnApi.applyColumnState({
    state: [{ colId: 'make', pinned: 'left' }],
    defaultState: { pinned: null },
  });
  this.gridApi.setFocusedCell(1, 'make');
  this.gridApi.startEditingCell({
    rowIndex: 1,
    colKey: 'make',
  });
},

onBtStopEditing() {
  this.gridColumnApi.applyColumnState({
    state: [{ colId: 'make', pinned: null }],
    defaultState: { pinned: null },
  });
  this.gridApi.stopEditing();
},
```